# Do Nonblocking PHP streams need a stream_select

Tags: php, sockets

I am writing a PHP application using the tcp stream wrapper. When using streams you're able to turn the connection to a non blocking mode.

```
stream_set_blocking($stream, 0);
stream_set_timeout($stream, 0);
```

I also noticed that there is a stream_select

> stream_select($stream, $stream, $stream, 0)

Following normal linux select I would not bother with the stuff above and just use select with no timeout to make sure it's non_blocking. I noticed the application "seems to work", not sure if because it's locally tested so the connection is super fast and so on. Or if because it's set to non_blocking i am wasting cycles calling select also.

Comment: It may be a good idea to introduce some `usleep()` into your locally tested code to simulate the effects of a production deployment in order to avoid such doubts.

Comment: do you need non-blocking behaviour?

Comment: @Fanis what is the usleep suppose to emulate?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it would be useful since i am writing a web server and a few other processes into the same core background process.

Comment: `usleep()` to simulate real world network-induced delays, since you're not sure if testing locally skews your results.